# Getting wrong elements in an array after comparing two array values

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have two arrays `villanStrength = [112,243,512,343,90,478]` and `playerStrength = [5,789,234,400,452,150]` of same length, I am comparing each value of array `playerStrength` with `villanStrength` and forming up an another array which will store the either 0 or 1 (false or true) based on comparison, but the output array I am getting is not desirable. Please help me...

my code:

```js
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');

var userInput =        //providing this externally from the file
1
6
112 243 512 343 90 478
5 789 234 400 452 150;

var testCases = "";
var numberOfPlayers = "";
var villanStrength = [];
var playerStrength = [];

process.stdin.on('data', (data) => {
    userInput = data;
    // console.log("user input = " + userInput);
    let res = userInput.split("\n");

    testCases = res[0];
    // for (i=1; i<=testCases; i++) {
        numberOfPlayers = res[1];
        // console.log("cases = " + testCases);
        // console.log("number of players = " + numberOfPlayers);

        villanStrength = res[2].split(" ");
        playerStrength = res[3].split(" ");
        console.log("villan Strength = " + villanStrength);
        console.log("player Strength = " + playerStrength);

        let isSmall = false;
        let comparisonResult = [];
        for (let j=0; j<villanStrength.length; j++) {
            for (let k=0; k<playerStrength.length; k++) {
                if (playerStrength[j] < villanStrength[k]) {
                    comparisonResult[k] = 1;                   //true = 1, false = 0
                } else {
                    comparisonResult[k] = 0;
                }
            }
            console.log("comparison result for " + j +":" + comparisonResult);
            if(comparisonResult.find((findOne) => {return findOne = 1;} )) {
                isSmall = true;
                console.log("LOSE");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isSmall === false) {
            console.log("Win");
        }

    // }
});
```

The output array is comparisonResult[] and the values inside comparisonResult I am getting is as below:

```
villan Strength = 112,243,512,343,90,478
player Strength = 5,789,234,400,452,150
comparison result for 0: 0,0,1,0,1,0           //this should be 1,1,1,1,1,1
comparison result for 1: 0,0,0,0,1,0
comparison result for 2: 0,1,1,1,1,1
comparison result for 3: 0,0,1,0,1,1
comparison result for 4: 0,0,1,0,1,1
comparison result for 5: 0,1,1,1,1,1
```

in the above result it is expected that the 'comparison result for 0' should be [1,1,1,1,1,1] but it is [0,0,1,0,1,0].

Comment: Each iteration through the `j` loop will overwrite the previous iterations values in the `comparisonResult` array so `comparisonResult` will contain only values from the last iteration of the `j` loop.  I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with that `comparisonResult` array.  To capture every value of every comparison you do, that array would have to contain `villanStrength.length * playerStrength.length` elements, not just `playerStrength.length` elements since you're comparing every element in `villanStrength` to every element in `playerStrength`.

Comment: You're looping `j` for `villanStrength` and `k` for `playerStrength`, then you get `[j]` from `playerStrength` and `[k]` from `villanStrength`... That's why a meaningful variable name is useful

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes it will overwrite, actually there is some more code below but I want to check the values stored inside the 'comparisonResult' array after every iteration but here the values stored are  not correct as far as I can see.

Comment: Well, you're only going to end up with a mix of results because only if `playerStrength[j] < villanStrength[k]`, then you overwrite the previous value, otherwise, you keep the previous value.  Really not sure what you're trying to accomplish at all.

Comment: @HaoWu that's all okay but don't you think the output that we are getting in array 'comparisonResult' is mathematically wrong?

Comment: When I run your code, I get `comparison result for 0:1,1,1,1,1,1`.  I do not get the results you show.

Comment: Your two loops are in the wrong order to get the results you seem to expect, i.e. the playerStrength loop needs to be the outer loop.

Comment: I edited your question to put your code into a runnable snippet.  It does NOT generate the results you say it does when run here.  So, either your real code is different than this or there's something wrong with the results you thought you were getting.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for that, I can see the output after running the code snippet is same as I am expecting but in my code I am getting different, might be because of wrong values in the array. I am changing the content of the question.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 I have made changes in the question now, please tell me why I am getting wrong output.

Comment: Well, now you changed the snippet into something else that can't be run in a browser and can't even be run in nodejs without appropriate data coming in.  I guess it should be removed from the snippet and just be a standalone code block.

Comment: Your code is comparing strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems with this code.

1. When you compare values in your arrays, **you are comparing strings, not numbers**.  The values you get from stdin are text values, not numeric values.  So, for example `'5' > '100'`.  I presume this is the major source of your issue.  If you want to do numeric comparisons, you need to convert the strings to numbers.
2. You are assuming that you get ALL your data on the first `data` event.  While that may usually be true, it is not guaranteed and you should not rely on it when programming.  You have to collect data in one or more `data` events until you have a full chunk of data you can process.

If you add these two log statements that show the actual contents of the array (not the `.toString()` conversion of the array):

```
console.log("villan strength: ", villanStrength);
console.log("player strength: ", playerStrength);
```

You will see this output:

```
villan strength:  [ '112', '243', '512', '343', '90', '478\r' ]
player strength:  [ '5', '789', '234', '400', '452', '150;\r' ]
```

Note, these are strings and when coming from my text file, there's a trailing `\r` too.

If you change this:

```
villanStrength = res[2].split(" ");
playerStrength = res[3].split(" ");
```

to this:

```
villanStrength = res[2].split(" ").map(item => parseInt(item.trim(), 10));
playerStrength = res[3].split(" ").map(item => parseInt(item.trim(), 10));
```

Then, it will trim off the newline and convert them to numbers and your comparisons will make sense.  This is why the code you posted originally in your question did not generate the wrong output because you hacked in an array of numbers (for purposes of the original question), but your original code was ending up with an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement, the playerStrength loop needs to be the outer loop and comparisonResult should be an array of arrays

```js
           villanStrength = [112,243,512,343,90,478] 
            playerStrength = [5,789,234,400,452,150]
            // ...
            let comparisonResult = [];                    //output array
            for (let j=0; j< playerStrength.length; j++) {
                 comparisonResult[j] = [];
                for (let k=0; k<villanStrength.length; k++) {
                    if (playerStrength[j] < villanStrength[k]) {
                        comparisonResult[j].push(1);                   //true = 1, false = 0
                    } else {
                        comparisonResult[j].push(0);    
                    }
                }
                console.log("comparison result for player " + j +":" + comparisonResult[j]);
             }
```

Comment: I have made some changes in the question, please tell me why I am getting that values in output array.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right you need to compare each value from array1 to array2 and generate a new array that show diffrent...

All you need is just one loop that can take both values and push result of comparison to another array

```
function compare() {
    const villanStrength = [112, 243, 512, 343, 90, 478];
    const playerStrength = [5, 789, 234, 400, 452, 150];
    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < villanStrength.length; i++) {
        const vVal = villanStrength[i];
        const pVal = playerStrength[i];

        if (pVal < vVal) {
            result.push(1);
            continue;
        }

        result.push(0);
    }

    console.log(result);
}
```

My suggestion for is to separate codes to smaller funtions so you can focus on each section